# Howe can i display proper page when i generate content via map function? Using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, map-function

Im working on website for MMA gym. Gym has many fighters. Every fighter has his own card profile. For cards i use map function and information like **name**, **nickname** i have in `array`.

I'd like create page about fighter. So when someone click on the card. Page will show up with correct info. For example when i click on fighter1 page with info about fighter1 will show up.

I've made some popup logic but i have no idea how display correct information.

popup logic

```
const Fighter1= ({setIsOpenPopup}) => {
  return (
    <Container onClick={() => setIsOpenPopup(false)}>
      <Content onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
        <Header>
          <HeaderH3>Title here</HeaderH3>
          <CloseBtn onClick={() => setIsOpenPopup(false)}>
          </CloseBtn>
        </Header>
        <InfoP>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
          Perferendis, molestiae.
        </InfoP>
        <FooterP>
          XXX
        </FooterP>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
export default Fighter1;
```

at this time i have folder with pages fighter1, fighter2 etc. Yes i wanted use map function but i have no idea how then display proper info too.. This is easier way i thing.

For **maping** fighter cards i use this standart map function. It's just `array` and `map`

```
const DataAthletes = () => {
  const athletes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'David',
      nickname: '"SPARŤAN"',
      lastName: 'Hošek',
      sport: 'MMA, BOX',
      secondLineSport: '',
      facebook: '/',
      instagram: '/',
      photo: Hosek,
      button: 'Zjistit více'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstName: 'Matůš',
      nickname: '"SLÁVISTA"',
      lastName: 'Juráček',
      sport: 'MMA, BOX',
      secondLineSport: '',
      facebook: '/',
      instagram: '/',
      photo: Juracek,
      button: 'Zjistit více'
    },
]


  return (
    <AthleteContainer id="athletes">
      <HeadingH2 size='3'>Naši Atleti</HeadingH2>
      <AthleteMainP>Aktuálně nás na profesionální úrovní representují tito atleti. RPG též representuje mnoho atletů
        na amatérské úrovni.
      </AthleteMainP>
      <CenterWrapper>
        <AthleteWrapper>
          {athletes.map(athlete =>
            <Athletes athlete={athlete}/>
          )}
        </AthleteWrapper>
      </CenterWrapper>
    </AthleteContainer>
  )
}

export default DataAthletes;
```

And finally in the end whole fighter card

```
const Athletes = ({athlete}) => {
  const [imgHover, setImgHover] = useState(false);

  const onHover = () => {
    setImgHover(!imgHover)
  }

  const [isOpenPopup, setIsOpenPopup] = useState(false);

  return (
      <AthleteCards onClick={() => setIsOpenPopup(true)}>
        {isOpenPopup &&
          <Popup setIsOpenPopup={setIsOpenPopup} />}
        <NameWrapperH3>
          <FirstName>{athlete.firstName}</FirstName>
          <Nickname>{athlete.nickname}</Nickname>
          <LastName>{athlete.lastName}</LastName>
        </NameWrapperH3>
        <SportWrapper>
          <SportName>{athlete.sport}</SportName>
          <SportName>{athlete.secondLineSport}</SportName>
        </SportWrapper>
        <SocialWrapper>
          <Link href={athlete.facebook}>
            <FacebookIcon/>
          </Link>
          <Link href={athlete.instagram}>
            <InstagramIcon/>
          </Link>
        </SocialWrapper>
        <ImgWrapper>
          <AthletePhoto src={athlete.photo}/>
        </ImgWrapper>
      </AthleteCards>
  )
}

export default Athletes;
```

I can say popup works relatively fine. There are some issues but i think it's CSS issue so it's for another topic maybe.

I'd like to ask with big pleased request. How can i display proper fighter page depending on which card i click please?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Here are some, from best to worst (imho): move the data fetching higher up so that the player data can be passed to both the list and the individual page, pass the page an id and have it fetch the full information, pass the data locally in a query string, save the data locally in storage (indexeddb)

Comment: Pass the playerId in popup or athlete component and retrieve the information of player based in the playerid. Display it on popup or separate page.